# complex query for many to many relatinoship in ef 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my project each user have one or more group and every group have one or more roles
And After user login I want to get the roles for this user using entity framework 3.
And These the models that I have.

User Model

```
public class User
    {

        public User()
        {
            userGroups = new List<UserGroup>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        [Required]
        public string Username{get;set;}

        public ICollection<UserGroup> userGroups{get;set;}

        
    }
```

Group Model

```
public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "groupName")]
        [Required]
        public string groupName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RoleGroup> roleGroups { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserGroup> userGroups { get; set; }

    }
```

UserGroup Model

```
public class UserGroup
    {
        public int userId{get;set;}
        public User user{get;set;}
        public int groupId{get;set;}
        public Group group{get;set;}
    }
```

Role Model

```
public class Role
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}

        public string roleName{get;set;}

        public string roleDescription{get;set;}
        public ICollection<RoleGroup> roleGroups{get;set;}
    }
```

RoleGroup Model

```
 public class RoleGroup
    {
        public int RoleId{get;set;}
        public Role role{get;set;}
        public int groupId{get;set;}
        public Group group{get;set;}
    }
```

what I want is get all roles for specific user using Id.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that the path from user to roles is fairly clear:

> user -> user groups <-> groups -> role groups <-> roles.

So it's not very complicated, the query can be like this:

```
//with lazy loading enabled
var userRoles = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == someId)
                      ?.userGroups
                      ?.SelectMany(e => e.group.roleGroups)
                      ?.Select(e => e.role)?.ToList();

//with lazy loading disabled
var userRoles = context.Users.Where(e => e.Id == someId)
                       .SelectMany(e => e.userGroups)
                       .SelectMany(e => e.group.roleGroups)
                       .Select(e => e.role).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the User, Group and Role table contains many to many relationship, you could use the `Include` and `ThenInclude` method to load the related data. Check the following query statement:

```
        //required using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        var result = (_context.User
            .Include(c => c.userGroups)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.group)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.roleGroups)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.role)
            .Where(c=>c.Id ==1)
            .SelectMany(c => c.userGroups.SelectMany(d => d.group.roleGroups
                    .Select(e => new { UserName = c.Username, 
                            GroupName = e.group.groupName,  
                            RoleName = e.role.roleName })))).ToList();
```

The Data Table as below (as we can see that the User "Tom" has two roles: "Admin" and "Manager"):

[image]

The query result like this:

[image]